# Bootstrap modal, thank you message, submit form, with required

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, submit, required

I have a site built with bootstrap framework. It has a form with a few required text inputs and a submit button. As it is was, after the submit button is clicked it opened a new blank html page with a thank you message. If the required fields are not filled in a warning occurs and the info is not submitted until the required fields are completed.

I want to change the thank you page to a thank you modal window. My problem is, with the thank you message set as a modal, the thank you modal fires with or without the required fields having info. I need the modal to not popup unless all required fields are filled in, anyone have a simple way to correct this?

```
<form id="contact-form" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php" method="post" target="blank">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for='name'>
                            Name</label>
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required placeholder="Enter Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for='email'>
                            Email Address</label> 
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required placeholder="Enter Email" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for='message'>
                            Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required
                            placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" name='submit' class="btn btn-skin pull-right" id="btnContactUs" value="Submit" target="blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalThanks">
                        Send Message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the description (not clear), I feel that, what you want is the client side validation of your form. Take a look at this plugin.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: Actually, I just figured out (remembered) that the thank you html page is called in my php file. Guessing there is not an easy way to not have the than you modal fire. 

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');